# Как поставить mysql на Debian 10 (testing) не прибегая к даунгрейду и VM?

Tags: mysql, linux, debian

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

> Чтение списков пакетов… Готово Построение дерева зависимостей
>   Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово Некоторые пакеты не могут быть
>   установлены. Возможно, то, что вы просите, неосуществимо, **или же вы
>   используете нестабильную версию дистрибутива**, где запрошенные вами
>   пакеты ещё не созданы или были удалены из Incoming. Следующая
>   информация, возможно, вам поможет:
>
> Следующие пакеты имеют неудовлетворённые зависимости:  mysql-server :
>   Зависит: mysql-community-server (= 8.0.16-2debian9) но он не будет
>   установлен E: Невозможно исправить ошибки: у вас зафиксированы
>   сломанные пакеты.

Я пытался ставить мускул 5.7 / 8.0

```
mysql-apt-config_0.8.8-1_all.deb
mysql-apt-config_0.8.12-1_all.deb
mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb
```

Частично мне это даже удавалось. 
Пакеты ставились в порядке обратном зависимостям, сервер стартовал но... не работал (не активный)

Comment: Cобрать mysql из исходников. Заодно и протестируете:)

Answer (score 3):

[С репозиториев debian 10](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=buster&searchon=names&keywords=mysql) - никак. mysql был удалён оттуда в пользу `mariadb` и метапакета `default-mysql-server` (который ставит только `mariadb` по зависимостям). Метапакет `mysql-server` выглядит сломанным в `buster`. Заморозка релиза уже была, так что обратно mysql скорей всего не появится в штатном репозитории вовсе. В `stretch` (debian 9) пакет `mysql-server` был уже переходным и единственное что делает - ставит всё тот же пакет `default-mysql-server`.

Если необходим именно `mysql` - что ж, всё плохо. Официально debian 10 пока не поддерживается и [репозиторием самого mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/). Присмотреться к mariadb повнимательнее, собрать mysql из исходников, поискать другие репозитории которым вы сможете доверить базу либо пытаться собирать франкенштейна с использованием пакетов от debian 9 или sid. Либо предметно (по логам) смотреть что такое "сервер стартовал но... не работал"

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ - использовать докер

1. Установить последнюю версию по [официальной инструкции](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/debian/)
2. Скачать образ mysql:

   ```
   docker pull mysql
   ```
3. Запустить:

   ```
   docker run --name mysql-oracle -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass -d -p33060:3306  mysql
   ```

   Тут указаны проброс порта 33060 хост-машины внутрь контейнера mysql
4. Проверка версии:

   ```
   mysql --port=33060 --protocol=tcp -uroot -ppass
   ```

   Выведет

   > Server version: 8.0.16 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Если докер-контейнер нужен постоянно (после перезагрузки), то надо добавить ключ `--restart=always`.

[Документация об этом образе](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql)

Answer (score 1):

я себе установил по этой инструкции, возможно и другим так же поможет. [описание установки mysql на debian 10](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-mysql-on-debian-10/)

вот основные команды. в принципе можно не думая вводить и выполнять.

```
wget http://repo.mysql.com/mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb

sudo apt install ./mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb
```

если нужен сервер не версии 8, который выбран по умолчанию, идем по первой кнопке и там выбираем, например 5.7. потом ок два раза.
после чего обновление списка пакетов и уже сама установка

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install mysql-server
```

надо выбрать новый секретный метод аутентификации или старый.
проверить результат можно

```
sudo systemctl status mysql
```

почему-то даже на сайте самого сервера нет этой инструкции, а только сложная из пакетов и написано что пока 10 версия не поддерживается. и рекомендуют следовать новым тенденциям и использовать мариядв, как и в упомянутой статье.
If your application does not have any specific requirements, you should stick with MariaDB, the default database system in Debian 10.

но, просматривая конфигурационные файлы, закралось подозрение что он и в этом случае устанавливает mariadb, но делает обманные действия чтобы все выглядело как mysql